# Connecting iOS, Android, and Rails App to One Database

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, database, api

My friends and I are developing a rails app (ruby), iOS app (swift), and android app (java). We are trying to figure out the best way to connect them all.

From our current research, we are under the impression that an API will need to be created with rails and the mobile apps will then have to communicate with that. Is this the only solution? I am also understand that apps can "pull" data from an api, but what about the other way around? We would like each application to be congruent with each other... for example, a record is created in the iOS app. As soon as this happens, the record should also be able to found on the rails app.

When thinking about it, it seems like all we would need is one database, and then have all of the apps connected to it. Would something like this work?

Having trouble finding solid information regarding this. If you know of any documentation, please pass it my way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to host database in cloud and access to that common database from all applications. If you host your database with any hosting provider, they will give you a connection string using which you can access from any application. See [Amazon AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the popular way to interface with your database would be to expose it through a REST framework. Doing this, it doesn't matter how many apps you want to be able to interact with the data, or what platform they are on.

Also, check out Kivy as an option for your mobile implementation, as it allows you to deploy to iOS and Android from a single code base. Of course, you may need to account for differences in hardware APIs, etc... But that would be easier, IMO, than maintaining multiple code bases.

Comment: Is it possible to load up swift code to Kivy for cross device compatibility or will I need to develop my whole app in Kivy framework?